# Casting error while saving in the database

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I am using Angular as frontend and NodeJS for the backend.

I have a route that saves the data received from the frontend to the database. When I execute the `save()` method, I get prompted the following error:

> err : ValidationError: conf.0: Cast to [Boolean] failed for value "[ {
> name: 'v', percentage: 2, type: false, status: true } ]" (type string)
> at path "conf.0"

Below is the route that stores the data:

```
app.post("/api/submitTaxCollection", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const submitTaxSchema = new addTaxesSchema(req.body);
  try {
    submitTaxSchema.save(function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log("err : " + err);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR : " + error);
    return res.send(error);
  }
});
```

and this is the schema.ts file:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Define a schema
var taxSchema = mongoose.Schema;

var AddTaxSchema = new taxSchema({
  parentId: String,
  conf: [
    {
      name: String,
      percentage: Number,
      type: Boolean,
      status: Boolean,
    },
  ],
});

var newTaxesSchema = mongoose.model("addTaxSchema", AddTaxSchema);

module.exports = newTaxesSchema;
```

In Angular, model is setup as below:

```
export class TaxRatesConfigurationsModel {
  name: string = "";
  percentage: number = 0;
  type: boolean = false;
  status: boolean = true;
}

export class TaxRatesModel {
  parentId: string = "";
  conf: TaxRatesConfigurationsModel[] = [];
}
```

and I am calling the API as below:

```
this._httpService
          .post(environment.url + "/api/submitTaxCollection", request)
          .subscribe((data) => {
            console.log(data);
          });
```

when I `console.log(req.body);`, I get the following printed to the console (Nodejs):

```
{
  parentId: '23948923nur8cw9yicnyu',
  conf: [ { name: 'v', percentage: 2, type: false, status: true } ]
}
```

and the error occurs in Nodejs
**What is causing this weird issue?**

Comment: error is from angular side or node.js side?

Comment: @GRD nodejs side

Comment: @GRD Updated the question to clarify that point, thank you

Comment: Try like this `const submitTaxSchema = new addTaxesSchema( JSON.parse (req.body));` and see what will be the result.

Comment: @GRD I get the following error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: Okay. Then I think check out mongoose type schema is correct or not.

Comment: @GRD it is working now after wrapping up the types in curly brackets like `name: { type: String, default: "" },`, Thank you